# What's the shortest input that makes TeX and/or TeX-based systems go into a loop?

Tags: macros, errors, expansion

The following 12-character input causes TeX to go into a loop.

```
\def\x{\x}\x
```

It won't crash, it won't produce an error message, it'll just sit there for ever, trying to compile the document (but not getting anywhere because no matter how many times it expands `\x`, it just gets `\x` back again).

Is there a shorter input that confounds TeX in a similar way?

Comment: Counterpoint: The OP in the linked question is interested primarily in finding ways to make (La)TeX go into a loop that don't rely simply on macro-expansion. However, the linked question does give an example of a nine-character input that causes a loop.

Comment: This should go on [code golf SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Hammerite When you say _in a similar way_, do you mean by macro expansion? Please clarify, I am beginning to feel that your question is a duplicate as indicated above. Are you asking something shorter than `\def~{~}~`? I am withholding my vote, with an inclination for close vote.

Comment: @MMA, I meant that the effect should be similar, not that the method of achieving it need be similar.

Comment: @Hammerite Then its is a duplicate, IMHO.